# JavaScript not running in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am currently having an issue with JavaScript with Rails. I am using Rails version 4.1.8 and I have a drop down menu that I found online using JavaScript to control it. Previously I had all of the js assets precompile seperately in app/config/initializers/assets but I decided that was not really the proper way to handle it. I now have all the js just added into application.js when I run rake assets:precompile but strangely, even though I changed the javascript_include_tag to application.js, the function for clicking on the text and expanding the menu does not work.

My code for the view I am trying to use the JavaScript from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Blueprint: Horizontal Drop-Down Menu</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Blueprint: Horizontal Drop-Down Menu" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="horizontal menu, microsoft menu, drop-down menu, mega menu, javascript, jquery, simple menu" />
  <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
  <%-#= stylesheet_link_tag 'component.css', :media => "all" -%>
  <%-#= stylesheet_link_tag 'default.css', :media => "all" -%>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css', :media => "all" %>

  <!---<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>---->
  <%-#= javascript_include_tag 'modernizr.custom.js' -%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js' %>
<!---</head>
  <body>--->
<div class="container">
  <header class="clearfix">
    <span>Catch phrase is catchy...</span>
    <a><%= link_to image_tag 'Western-Maryland_AHEC_logo.png', controller: "home"%></a>

    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <!---<nav>
    <a href="http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/" class="icon-arrow-left" data-info="previous Blueprint">Previous Blueprint</a>
    <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=14426" class="icon-drop" data-info="back to the Codrops article">back to the Codrops article</a>
    </nav>--not working for now-->
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Views</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Major Activities</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Strategic Action Plan</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>News</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Annual Reports</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>People</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Caucuses</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Dental</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Meetings</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Dietetic</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Minutes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Nutrition Resources</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Area Registered Dietitians Directory</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Western Maryland Regional Medical Center Dietitians</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Massage Therapy</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Minutes</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Games</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">News and Events</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Utilities</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Education</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Professionals</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Utilities</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Entertainment</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Holy Cannoli</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Resources</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Utilities</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Education</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Professionals</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<!---<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js"></script>---->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' %>
<%-#= javascript_include_tag 'cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js' -%>
<script>
    $(function() {
        cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<%= link_to root_url do %>
    <%= image_tag 'Western-Maryland_AHEC_logo.png'%> <!--, width: 136, height: 67, alt: 'Western Maryland Area Health Education Center'%> -->
<% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript from my precompiled application.js looks like:

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

    var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ),
        $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
        $body = $( 'body' ),
        current = -1;

    function init() {
        $menuItems.on( 'click', open );
        $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
    }

    function open( event ) {

        if( current !== -1 ) {
            $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        }

        var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
            idx = $item.index();

        if( current === idx ) {
            $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = -1;
        }
        else {
            $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = idx;
            $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
        }

        return false;

    }

    function close( event ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = -1;
    }

    return { init : init };
```

I feel like this is a stupid question but I am totally lost as to why it works when I precompile these assets seperately but it does not work when I try to reference them with application.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try moving application.js after jquery. Your application.js is referencing "$" which is jquery and it doesn't look like your javascript is waiting for the rest of page to be loaded, so it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: You have script tags at the header and footer. This is confusing and I don't understand why you do that.
As previous comment suggested, bring some order into the code and include jQuery before you use it.

Comment: I moved the jQuery above application.js but it still has the same problem. In the original html code, it looks like it includes 3 JavaScripts. It looks for modernizer.js, the jQuery, then a script that has the function that I listed above. Could it be necessary to load them in that order? If so how can that be done with Rails?

Answer (score 0):

In my part of view , You can try add the jquery required file in top order of the application.js file . And after that all in orders . Thus it can help.